# Converting grid coordinates

Tags: math

So I have a grid which is in one form and im trying to get the X and Y.

[image]

Is there a formula where I could turn for example 12 into 2,2 or 14 to 2,3

Also is there a name for this type of grid?

```
 static int getX(int z)
        {
             int count = 0;
            int res = 0;
            int curr = 0;
            for(int temp = z; temp > 0; temp >>= 1)
            {
                    if(count % 2 ==0)
                    {
                       res += ((temp & 1) << curr);
                        curr++;
                    }
                      count++;                
            }   

            return res;
        }


        static int getY(int z)
        {
             int count = 0;
            int res = 0;
            int curr = 0;
            for(int temp = z; temp > 0; temp >>= 1)
            {
                    if(count % 2 ==1)
                    {
                       res += ((temp & 1) << curr);
                        curr++;
                    }
                      count++;                
            }   

            return res;
        }
```

Comment: If you can't find a pattern, you can use a dictionary/associative array to map each of your input numbers (eg. 12) to an output coordinate (eg. (2,2)).

Comment: That looks like a "Z-order curve".

Comment: @Sneftel That looks like it :) I will google around that.

Answer (score 0):

As Sneftel observed, this looks like a [Z-order curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve). As such, you can convert coordinates by interleaving binary representations. So your examples are

```
 0 1 0  x=2       0 1 0  x=2
0 1 0   y=2      0 1 1   y=3
001100  p=12     001110  p=14
```

So to get *x* and *y* coordinates from the cell number *p*, you assign the bits of *p* alternatingly to *x* and *y*. This kind of bit arithmetic is pretty hard to express using elementary arithmetic operations, and there is no generally recognized formula symbol for this that I'm aware of, but the idea is quite simple.

Comment: Thanks MvG. I added some code. Any way that can be optimised?

Comment: @John: The web will likely provide you with answers. Perhaps using precomputations for blocks of moderate bit size, or maybe using recent processor hardware instructions.